# AWS file system for keeping redundant storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an application which can be deployed as a standalone server but requires minimum downtime. The configuration for the application are stored in the application directory as .xml files. This setup is deployed on AWS. The instance is kept on auto-scaling group. Is taking the AWS EFS to deploy the application directory the best approach for such applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on the specific application, and for example how if it's stateless. And otherwise how it handles state.

But below a few (but not all) ways to handle this specific problem:

- You could use an EFS volume to store your application configuration, but then your configuration is not versioned.
- You could build versions of your application as an AMI and then deploy these AMIs to your Autoscaling group. So when changing the configuration, you build new ami's and then deploy these to your autoscaler.
- You could store your configuration files in an S3 bucket and have your application grab these from the bucket when starting up. S3 buckets natively support versioning, so going back a version of your configuration is easy.

It really depends on the specific requirements of your deployment and your application stack. 
Personally I do not like relying on an NFS mount for the configuration of my application. It also feels like a bit much.

Comment: `It also feels like a bit much` is the very reason I don't want to use EFS for such. We are already using EFS and thus was recommended by others here.

Answer (score 2):

One option for storing configuration data that is often overlooked is [Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html), which is a feature of [EC2 Systems Manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html).

> Parameter Store centralizes the management of configuration data. You
>   can use Parameter Store to store passwords, license keys, or database
>   connection strings that you commonly reference in scripts, commands,
>   or other automation and configuration workflows.

Comment: Bonus worth mentioning, the parameter store "just works," and doesn't actually require you to use any other parts of EC2 Systems Manager.